# React Context and memo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a context that wraps a Navbar (where the user enters a keyword) and a Dashboard that shows 11 charts based on the keyword. The context simply keeps track of the term but it is making the entire application very slow, even taking up to 4 minutes when fetching data from an api that is running on localhost. Furthermore, it also takes a while until it starts fetching the data, so I guess I am doing something in terms of context state management. This is what my code would look like:

```
<SearchContext.Provider value={{
        term: state.term,
        // recentSearches: state.recentSearches,
        // addToRecentSearches,
        searchTerm,
        clearTerm,
      }}
>
  <HomeNavbar />
  <Dashboard/>
</SearchContext.Provider>
```

Comment: Where do you manage/change `state.term`, `searchTerm`, etc, and who consume the search context? More or less it's the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445194/using-context-and-usereducer-in-a-functional-component-caused-all-child-comp/67445471#67445471

Comment: I manage searchTerm in the HomeNavbar component 
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    searchTerm(inputRef.current.value);
    inputRef.current.value = '';
  };
const searchTerm = (term) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_TERM,
      payload: term,
    });
  };
 <SearchContext.Provider
      value={{
        term: state.term,
        // recentSearches: state.recentSearches,
        // addToRecentSearches,
        searchTerm,
        clearTerm,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </SearchContext.Provider>

Comment: Try to move as many top-level component that manage state to not render components directly, but inject them using `children` instead. As in, create a new component, like `SearchProvider` that use `SearchContext.Provider`, but `<HomeNavbar />` and other components are passed through `children` to it instead.

Comment: <SearchState>
          {/* Header */}
          <HomeNavbar />
            <Dashboard></Dashboard>
        </SearchState> where <SearchState> takes props and returns return (
    <SearchContext.Provider
      value={value}
    >
      {props.children}
    </SearchContext.Provider>
  );
Is that what you mean?

Comment: HomeNavbar is the component that dispatches the actions that modify state